# Export date format in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I've got a regional based solution for Dynamics CRM 2011 (online).

You can set this via Settings / Administration / System Settings / Formats.  But what do I need to include when exporting my solution?

When I go through the normal process to export a solution, I see Auto-numbering, Calendar, Customization etc.

Selecting these didn't change the date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regional settings are not going to be exported via a solution, since the idea is that an organization could have several different solutions installed at the same time. You'll have to set up each new organization manually with the correct language, date format, etc.